# jQuery AJAX call working in IE but not FF?

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://services.somewhere.com/MethodName',
            data: { 'param1':'something', 'param2': 'somethingElse' },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(view) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: **What's** not working? What error do you get?  Error messages exist for a reason :)

Comment: is there an error in firefox, or perhaps using something like firebug to track the request and/or validate for javascript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sridhar_subra/116/) which clearly explains clearly how to consume web services